Inconsistent CSS behavior for a custom JavaScript ToolTip
I created some "onmouseover" Tooltip on my site. As you will see in the code below, there are two Tooltips, associated with two different div elements.
I have set breakpoints in the script file and determined that both elements are correctly firing the onmouseover and onmouseout events and that each popup span element is correctly being found with the show class properly added/removed.
However, only the second one (quantity) works fine. The first one (remove) will not appear. Can anyone spot what I am missing?
(Anyone familiar with WordPress/WooCommerce will recognize this is a WC site. I mention it in case there may be some conflict I can't see in the debug window styles.)
The code below is adapted from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp (giving credit where credit is due!):


function togglePopup(element, onoff) {
    var popup = document.getElementById(element.id + "_popup");
    if (popup) {
        if (onoff) {
            popup.classList.add("show");
        }
        else {
            popup.classList.remove("show");
        }
    }
}
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
<br><br>
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
         <td class="product-remove">
            <div class="popup" onmouseover="togglePopup(this, true);" onmouseout="togglePopup(this, false);" id="addon_remove_link">
               <label class="remove">&times;</label>
               <span class="popuptext" id="addon_remove_link_popup">To remove add-on items, you must remove associated products</span>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantity">
            <div class="quantity popup" onmouseover="togglePopup(this, true);" onmouseout="togglePopup(this, false);" id="addon_quantity">
               <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_6658f8f611307">Thread - GutermannMatching thread for selected items quantity</label>
               <input readonly type="number" id="quantity_6658f8f611307" class="input-text qty text" name="cart[8f818faae39eca624255ff021f2f2afb][qty]" value="1" aria-label="Product quantity" size="4" min="0" max="100" step="1" placeholder="" inputmode="" autocomplete="off" />
               <span class="popuptext" id="addon_quantity_popup">To change add-on quantities, you must add/remove associated products</span>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>




What you are using is called a tooltip, but not a popup… There are already plenty of working tooltip examples and libraries, and there are also multiple jQuery libraries. You could use included jQuery-UI Tooltip or better jQuery Tooltipster plugin... and many more.

Made your code into an executable snippet, and both tooltips appear to work fine. Depending on where the table is located on your page, and whether there is enough space around it, they might perhaps get partially hidden though? (I added two <br> in the snippet, to make the table go down a bit.) We'll need a [mre] from you that actually helps reproduce the issue.

Thanks for the helpful guidance. I tried to create a reproducible example by putting the excerpted code into a standalone html file, but I wasn't able to reproduce it, as others here pointed out in the comments. The tooltips worked as expected.
HOWEVER, in the process of doing that, I changed the id attributes on the div and span elements in the remove section from "addon_remove_link" and "addon_remove_link_popup" to "addon_remove" and "addon_remove_popup". This worked!
I don't know why it wasn't a problem in my standalone html file but was a problem in the wordpress/woocommerce site. Changing the id attributes to "addon_remove_link2" and "addon_remove_link2_popup" also worked. So something about the specific id attributes I used was a problem. This was true even if I moved the id attribute and the onmouseover and onmouseout events to the label itself instead of the div.
So the problem is solved, though probably unsatisfactorily so. Just posting this to close the loop, thank others for the edits to my question to fix my terminology and clear up the code snippet, and in case it's helpful for others.
